# Advanced Iterator slicing :Is there a way to slice from a given index to another given index and create a separate list for each of these elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So we are given two lists.

```
groups= `[[0,1],[2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]

A= [[[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[2]], [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]
```

How do we replace the 0 and 1 in list A with a 0,2 with 1, 3 and 4 and 5 with 2 and 6,7,8,9 with 3 (ie their corresponding index in groups).
Output:
    A= [[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[1]], [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]

How do we approach such a problem?

Comment: First attempt: just write a (double) for-loop. Not pretty, but it may be good enough for your purposes, and could be more flexible than any other solution.

Comment: oh thanks ! Yeah sorry that was an error. I changed the question

Comment: Please be so kind when editing not to completely revert the previous edits that made the question much more readable with the use of code blocks. The question has now become unreadable again.

Answer (score 2):

A simple comprehension would do the trick:

```
a, b, c, d = [[l[i] for i in g] for g in groups]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/PrivateDarkturquoiseWordprocessor)